# Trying to add a reference cell in the middle of a value using an IF function on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Looking to link the information from another cell into an if statement.
This is in use of automating certian narative reports.

```
=IF(Scores!F160= "Y"," The GAI was {CELL HERE} which is significantly higher than the FSIQ.", "")
```

The Cell here would be linked to another cell with a number indicating a score a student received.
Unsure how I would set that up.

Answer (score 0):

interupt it with `&` like:

```
=IF(Scores!F160= "Y", "The GAI was "&A1&" which is significantly higher than the FSIQ.", )
```